# How I can open a Jython console in Java-ee application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jython

I have a Java-ee application (running in Tomcat), and I want to run in the backend a Jython-console  that share the memory with the application.

My purpose is to control the application with Jython. Then
I can change some shared variables or I can see the state of the server, etc

Is it possible?